# Linear Map Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $f$ is a bijection and linear map such that $f \colon E \to F$. Could someone help me prove that the inverse $f^{-1} \colon F \to E$ is also linear?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint. Let's call $g$ the inverse of $f$, so that $g(f(x))=x$ and $f(g(y))=y$.

To prove that $g$ is linear you need to prove that $g(ax)=ag(x)$ and $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

For the first one of these, we know that $f(ay)=af(y)$ since $f$ is linear. Applying $g$ to both sides we get

$$g(f(ay)) = g(af(y))$$

which reduces to

$$ay = g(af(y))$$

and finally defining $y=g(x)$, so that $f(y)=x$, we get

$$ag(x) = g(ax)$$

Now can you see how to prove the second part?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y_1, y_2 \in F$.  We wish to show $f^{-1}(y_1 + y_2) = f^{-1}(y_1) + f^{-1}(y_2)$.

Since $f$ is a bijection, we know there exist $x_1, x_2 \in E$ with $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_2) = y_2$.  From this and linearity of $f$, you can justify the following:
$$\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(y_1 + y_2) &= f^{-1}\left(f(x_1) + f(x_2)\right)\\
&= f^{-1}\left(f(x_1 + x_2)\right)\\
&= x_1 + x_2\\
&= f^{-1}(y_1) + f^{-1}(y_2)
\end{align*}$$

Try similar reasoning for the other part (or follow Chris Taylor's advice).